# check every element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What is the most efficient way to check a certain condition on every element of an array and return false if one or more elements do not meet the condition, for example, I have this array for example

```
arr = ["foo","azeaze", "wazeazerar"]
    for(var ar in arr){
      if(ar.length > 5){
        console.log(false)
      }else{
        console.log(true)
      } 
    }
```

as you can see it return true even if the element `"foo"` `length` is not greater than 5

Comment: Have you tried debugging this on your own to see what `ar` contains?

Comment: It marked as duplicated even if it dosent answear my question

Comment: Sure, it does: you should not use `for... in` if you want to iterate over the values of an array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.every()` in a one line function

```js
arr = ["foo","azeaze", "wazeazerar"]

const isittrue = currentval =>  currentval.length > 2

console.log(arr.every(isittrue));
```

```js
 arr = ["foo","azeaze", "wazeazerar"]
    console.log(arr.every(elem => elem.length >= 5))
```

Comment: Thank you sir , thankfully you did answear my question before the admin mark it as duplicated because i didnt understund why he mark it as duplicated even if it wasnt what I was asking